# What's the correct syntax for escapes and captures in a perl one-liner?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, latex, doxygen

I'm attempting to use pandoc to convert latex files (which were automatically generated by doxygen) to .docx format. I have encountered an error, perhaps in doxygen, which allows *some* characters that should be escaped (`_` and `%`) to go unescaped in the `DoxyCode` latex environment. Some underscores occur in filenames, and are inside braces. Those should not be escaped.

I wrote a perl one-liner that locates any underscores or percents that *aren't* between braces, and replaces them with a backslash followed by the same character:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!\\)([_%])(?![^{]+})/\\$1/g' test.tex
```

This works as expected. However, I then discovered that some of the files contain, e.g., an initializer list within braces, with some variables containing underscores, inside a `DoxyCode` environment. So I need a perl script that can recognize when the underscore or percent is between `\begin{DoxyCode}` and `\end{DoxyCode}` and insert a backslash if there be none.

The regex for this command is working; see https://regex101.com/r/gsQm2L/2

Although it only grabs the first match. I'm hoping perl can grab other matches, but I may be mistaken.

The command I have is

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=begin\{DoxyCode})([\s\S]+?[^\\])([_%])([\s\S]+?)(?=end\{DoxyCode})/$1\\$2$3/g' test.tex
```

but it fails to make any changes. (I tried not escaping the left braces, but I got an error: `Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;` etc.) I can't tell whether it's failing to find matches or failing to replace them because my capture syntax is incorrect.

For both the first and second example, the original contents of test.tex are as follows:

```
\begin{DoxyCode}                                                                                                     
17 This is some code that contains an_undersc_ore and                                                                
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_unders_core                                                        
19 for good measure.                                                                                                 
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a %percent sign                                                 
21 that is unescaped.                                                                                                
\end{DoxyCode}                                                                                                       

Here is some other stuff that may contain \index{things_not_to_be_escaped}.                                          

\begin{DoxyCode}                                                                                                     
17 This is some code that contains an_underscore and                                                                 
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_underscore                                                         
19 for good measure.                                                                                                 
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign                                                
21 that is escaped.                                                                                                  
\end{DoxyCode}
```

The desired content of test.tex, after running the perl command, would be the following:

```
\begin{DoxyCode}                                                                                                     
17 This is some code that contains an\_undersc\_ore and                                                                
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped\_unders\_core                                                        
19 for good measure.                                                                                                 
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign                                                 
21 that is unescaped.                                                                                                
\end{DoxyCode}                                                                                                       

Here is some other stuff that may contain \index{things_not_to_be_escaped}.                                          

\begin{DoxyCode}                                                                                                     
17 This is some code that contains an\_underscore and                                                                 
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped\_underscore                                                         
19 for good measure.                                                                                                 
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign                                                
21 that is escaped.                                                                                                  
\end{DoxyCode}
```

**Why is my perl one-liner failing? And how do I get the desired output?** I'm by no means a perl or regex expert, so I welcome feedback on other errors.

In case it's relevant, I'm working on debian stretch, and `perl --version` returns

```
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 85 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: A simple way?  Write a script.  A one-liner is clearly pushing it, no?

Comment: So escape `[_%]` only inside the `DoxyCode` (Latex) environment, unless it's `{%inside_braces}` (so leave these unescaped) ... correct? (And unless it's already escaped of course)

Comment: You wrote that the problem might be a problem in doxygen (but you were not sure) and it it is always the best to fix a problem at the source of the problems. Would be good to know a couple of things: 1) which version of doxygen are you using? 2) when generating the doxygen LaTeX code can you also build the pdf in the `latex` directory? 3) can you give an example of the source code that gives the problems.

Comment: @zdim creating a workaround is not the best way. One should not do this unless there is no other solution. Best is to see whether the problem can be solved in the generating program (or even in the source code being documented).

Comment: @albert Sure, I absolutely agree. But that's not what they asked.  It's good to inquire with OP whether it is possible to get to the actual problem but please remember to also keep in mind what they actually asked.  Also, treating the error that causes this smells like a different question altogether.

Comment: @zdim I hope OP comes up with some small code that provokes the problem.

Comment: zdim, that's the correct description of the problem. @albert, I'm using doxygen 1.8.13, which is what's available with debian, but is a few years old. I have already worked a few issues with doxygen involving the tabu package and have had to pare down the doxygen.sty (and frankly, a lot of style doesn't make it into .docx anyway). The code base is LARGE, several years old, and not mine, and my task to document it is a fairly quick turnaround, so I don't have much patience or leeway to explore doxygen's idiosyncracies... To answer your question, I was not able to generate a PDF.

Comment: The error message I get is : `Error at "afile.tex" (line 87, column 57):
unexpected _
expecting \end{alltt}` and this corresponds to a location inside the `DoxyCode` environment. There's nothing wrong with the code itself; it's appropriate for it to have `%` and `_` characters.

Comment: And to clarify, the effort to create a PDF failed silently.

Comment: Indeed doxygen 1.8.13 is from December 2016, since that time some things have changed. I would advise to get the doxygen version 1.8.16 (or even the master version) and compile it. There are some changes that you will benefit from  (will also help for the tabu problem). When you see that something is going wrong  it is probably quite easy to locate the file rom which the code comes and one can just try to generate the documentation for this file. Without more details it is not possible to fix the problems.I think investing just a little bit getting 1.8.16 will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: I don;t know why you choose pandoc to generate `.doxc` files from LaTeX as generated by doxygen, but did you have a look at the rtf output generated by doxygen (this is probably less perfect than the LaTeX output but maybe worthwhile do do a quick tests, and here I would certainly advise to use version 1.8.16).

Comment: I didn't realize the pathway to docx from RTF would be so easy! Upon looking at the RTF output, I will go that route. MUCH simpler. Thanks for your time, @albert

Comment: @easybeso Great!  (So this question isn't of interest anymore?)

Comment: Big question for me is why does one want to have source code documentation in word format. Note that doxygen also can do other types of documentation. E.g. the doxygen manual is generated by doxygen

Comment: @albert, I wish it weren't so, but it's not my choice to make. In my industry, word is unfortunately the standard for documenting software and everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, while the "right" way to do this is with a regex parser, it's still simple enough that you could do it with a one liner.  The key is doing a two stage substitution.  I added a use case for literal backslashes (\) that are not starting an escape for a _ or %.  If there could be other embedded {} then they can be excluded with the same paradigm.

```
$text = <<'EOF';
\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an_undersc_ore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_unders_core
19 for good measure. A literal \ and a literal \\_.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a %percent sign
21 that is unescaped.
\end{DoxyCode}

Here is some other stuff that may contain \index{things_not_to_be_escaped}.

\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an_underscore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_underscore
19 for good measure. A literal \\%.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign
21 that is escaped.
\end{DoxyCode}
EOF

print "before:\n$text\n\n";
$text =~ s{\Q\begin{DoxyCode}\E\K(.+?)(\Q\end{DoxyCode}\E)}{
    my($t,$e) = ($1,$2);
    $t =~ s{(\\\\ | \\?[_%])}{1==length $1 ? "\\$1" : $1}egsx; "$t$e";
}egs;
print "after:\n$text\n";
```

Output:

```
before:
\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an_undersc_ore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_unders_core
19 for good measure. A literal \ and a literal \\_.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a %percent sign
21 that is unescaped.
\end{DoxyCode}

Here is some other stuff that may contain \index{things_not_to_be_escaped}.

\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an_underscore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped_underscore
19 for good measure. A literal \\%.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign
21 that is escaped.
\end{DoxyCode}


after:
\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an\_undersc\_ore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped\_unders\_core
19 for good measure. A literal \ and a literal \\\_.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign
21 that is unescaped.
\end{DoxyCode}

Here is some other stuff that may contain \index{things_not_to_be_escaped}.

\begin{DoxyCode}
17 This is some code that contains an\_underscore and
18 an escaped\_underscore. Plus another unescaped\_underscore
19 for good measure. A literal \\\%.
20 As if that was not "bad" enough, it also contains a \%percent sign
21 that is escaped.
\end{DoxyCode}
```

Also read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators.  Pay special attention the \G assertion and the /gc flags.  That is how you would write a proper parser for this task.

HTH

Comment: How does this exclude stuff inside `{...}` (possibly nested), inside `DoxyCode`? One requirement

Comment: Thanks. I think this would get me the rest of the way.

Comment: It wasn't clear if embedded {} were part of the problem.  Adding them is simple:

`$t =~ s{(\\\\ | \{.+?\} | \\?[_%])}`

Any non-single character exclude can be added to this list.

Comment: "_Adding them is simple:..._" -- not so: What you show fails for nested ones (quite possible in Latex); if you were to relax the `?` then of course it wouldn't work at all.  Altogether this is a complex enough parsing problem (unless there are simplifications that OP can accept in their use cases)

Comment: There was nothing about nested {} tags in the OP.  If there could only be one level inside the begin/end then my last is fine.  If there could be any depth of nested {} tags that's simple as well. Well kind of.

Full recursion:
`$t =~ s{(\\\\ | (\{ (?: [^\{]++ | (?-1) )* \}) | \\?[_%])}  `